# Regular expression for number search

Tags: regex, perl, search

I need a regular expression that will find a number(s) that is not inside parenthesis.
Example  abcd 1 (35) (df)

It would only see the 1.

Is this very complex? I've tried and had no luck.
Thanks for any help

Comment: What programming language are you using? They all use regexes a little bit differently.

Comment: Post what you've tried and we'll modify.

Comment: It should be Perl specific. According to the editor I'm using. I'll try and find the old example I was using and post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite hard but something like this will probably do:

```
^(?:\()(\d+)(?:[^)])|(?:[^(0-9]|^)(\d+)(?:[^)0-9]|^)|(?:[^(])(\d+)(?:\))$
```

The problem is to match `(123`, `123)` and also to not match the string `123` as the number `2` between the non-parentheses characters `1` and `3`. Also there are probably some edge cases for start of and end of string.

My suggestion is to not use a regex for this. Maybe a regex that matches numbers and then use the capture info to check if the surrounding characters are not parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

An easy solution is to first remove the unwanted values:

```
my $string = "abcd 12 (35) (df) 2311,22";
$string =~ s/\(\d+\)//g;         # remove numbers within parens
my @numbers = $string =~ /\d+/g; # extract the numbers
```

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression would be:

```
^[a-z]+ ([0-9]+) \([0-9]+\) \([a-z]+\)$
```

The result is the first (and only) matching group of the regex.

Maybe you want to remove the `^` and `$` if the regex should not match only if it’s the content of a whole single line. You can also use `[a-zA-Z]` or `[[:alpha:]]`. This depends on the regular expression engine you use and, of course, the content you want to match.

Example perl code:

```
if (m/^[a-z]+ ([0-9]+) \([0-9]+\) \([a-z]+\)$/) {
  print("$1\n");
}
```

Please note that your question contains not enough information to make a good answer possible (you did not say anything about the general format of your expression, for example if you want to match integers or floating points)

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
/(?:^|[^\d(])(\d+)(?:[^\d)]|$)/
```

? This matches a string of digits (`\d+`) that are

- preceded by the beginning of the string, or a character that is not a digit or an open parenthesis (`(?:^|[^\d(])`)
- succeeded by the end of the string, or by a character that is not a digit or a close parenthesis (`(?:[^\d)]|$)`)